# Function burnfrom error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, erc-20

I have created a contract using Remix.

When I run the function `burnFrom()`, it shows:

```
gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) onlyOwner public returns 
(bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             
    totalSupply -= _value;                              
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As the error says, the transaction always fails. You need to check that all require conditions are fullfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are either using the javascript VM or that you have metamask unlocked and connected to a test net if using injected web3.

Make sure you have an allowance mapping that looks like this:

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
```

And that your Burn event looks like this:

```
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);
```

If you have both of these correct there is probably something wrong with the onlyOwner modifier.

Comment: OP must have declared these mappings else he would be getting compile time error in remix. The code compiled successfully means there is no cases that he missed declarations.